# Problem adding credit card source to an existing customer

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I try to add a new credit card to an existing customer but I get this error:

> Received unknown parameter: card

I figure out how to verify if a card already exists using `StripeTokenService` to retrieve the card fingerprint, but I'm stuck trying to add that card to the customer.

My code look like this:

```
var sourceService = new Stripe.StripeSourceService();

// Get customer with current payment source.
var stripeCustomer = customerService.Get(stripeCustomerWithAccount.Id, new Stripe.StripeRequestOptions { ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeSecretKey"] });

// Set Stripe Customer Id and Stripe Token options.
var tokenService = new Stripe.StripeTokenService();
var stripeToken = tokenService.Get(tokenId, new Stripe.StripeRequestOptions { ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeSecretKey"] });

// Check if credit card already exists.
if (!CreditCardExists(stripeCustomer, stripeToken))
{
    // Create new credit card.
    var sourceOptions = new StripeNet.StripeSourceCreateOptions()
    {
        Customer = stripeCustomer.Id,
        Card = new StripeNet.StripeCreditCardOptions
        {
            TokenId = stripeToken.StripeCard.Id 
        }                            
    };

    var source = sourceService.Create(sourceOptions, new Stripe.StripeRequestOptions { ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeSecretKey"] });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out how and I will share my answer:

```
if (!CreditCardExists(stripeCustomer, stripeToken))
{ 
    var creditCardService = new StripeNet.StripeCardService();
    var creditCardOptions = new StripeNet.StripeCardCreateOptions { SourceToken = tokenId };

    var creditCard = creditCardService.Create(stripeCustomer.Id, creditCardOptions, new StripeNet.StripeRequestOptions { ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeSecretKey"] });

    // The only way I found to get customer with all sources...
    stripeCustomer = customerService.Get(stripeCustomerWithAccount.Id, new StripeNet.StripeRequestOptions { ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeSecretKey"] });
}
```